# jQuery / AJAX - Abort isn't aborting

Tags: jquery, ajax

Neither of these are aborting - it still places the result of compareusername.php's POST into #userRegexJavascriptResponse.  How do I make abort work properly?

```
var xhr = $.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "compareusername.php",
data: {"userCreation": $('#userCreation').val()},
success: function(msg){
    $("#userRegexJavascriptResponse").text(msg);
}
});
xhr(); 
xhr.abort();
```

---

```
var xhr = $.post("compareusername.php", { userCreation:$('#userCreation').val() 
}, function(data){
$("#userRegexJavascriptResponse").text(data);
});
xhr();
xhr.abort();
```

Comment: Are you sure it's not just finishing by the time it gets to the abort?

Comment: @Vld Yes, see the code above. I abort it immediately after calling it, no if statements or sleeping.